# Jenkins Change Assembly Info Plugin not working on Linux Host and Windows Slave

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I have a configuration using a Linux Jenkins master and a Windows 10 slave.  I'm using it to do an msbuild operation on the slave and generate an install executable as an artifact.  I have this working on a Jenkins Windows 10 master system (same one I'm using as a slave), and this all works fine.  However, when I run the same job remotely I get the dreaded "CS1031" error:

Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(1,1): error CS1031: Type expected [C:\slave2Workspace\workspace\SDB Projects\CCMonitor\CCMonitor\CCMonitor\CCMonitor.csproj]

This is pointing at the first character in the file.  If I omit the job step with the Change Assembly Info plugin, everything works fine and I get the output correct.  What I found was that the AssemblyInfo.cs file was missing the characters 0xEB 0xBB at the front of the file -- these somehow got dropped in the translation.  Sounds like a character set issue, but it is only an issue with this plugin step.

Is there something that needs to be configured differently?

thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

So I had this same issue today and found the solution.  Not sure if you ever figured this one out, so I wanted to drop the solution just in case.

Turned out to be an encoding issue.  The assembly file is encoded UTF-8 with signature. As a workaround to avoid the characters being added to the beginning of the file, change the encoding to UTF-8 without signature.

I did this by opening the files in notepad++ and then selecting Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with Visual Studio (2017 in my case)

1. Open the file with the problem
2. Select File | Save  As
3. On the Save button there is drop down with option stating **Save with Encoding**
4. In the list with encodings select **UTF-8 without signature**

VS may tell you that there is already such file, you select to overwrite it.
Commit>Push with your source control (git in my case), and voila - that's it.